# Pass React component as props to be used as a template to render nodes in a TreeView

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a flexible `<TreeView />` component, where the user will be able to inject his own `<TreeNode />`, as an HTML template.

What I currently do works, but I can't set the propTypes as mandatory with my design pattern, because the `<TreeNode />` component only receive its props when I use it in `<TreeView />`, in a `map` function.

**Is there a better way to do this so I can use mandatory propTypes?**

**TreeNode.js**:

```
const TreeNode = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{props.id}</p>
            <p>{props.nodeTitle}</p>
            <p>{props.nodeDescription}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**TreeView.js**, very simplified:

```
export class TreeView extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const childrenList = props.treeViewData.map((treeNodeData) => {
            const treeNodeTemplateProps = {
                id: treeNodeData.id,
                nodeTitle: treeNodeData.nodeTitle,
                nodeDescription: treeNodeData.nodeDescription
            }              
            const treeNodeTemplate = this.props.treeNodeTemplate(treeNodeTemplateProps )
            return (
                {treeNodeTemplate}
            )
        })

        return <div>{childrenList}</div>
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import { TreeView } from './TreeView'
import { treeViewData } from './treeViewData'
import { TreeNode } from './TreeNode'

const element = <TreeView 
    treeViewData={treeViewData}
    treeNodeTemplate={TreeNode} />

ReactDOM.render(element , document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: It's a lot simpler than you might think -> `return <this.props.treeNodeTemplate {...treeNodeTemplateProps} />`

Answer (score 1):

While treenode is a functional component you can provide propTypes to it as you would do with another component:

```js
const TreeNode = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{props.id}</p>
            <p>{props.nodeTitle}</p>
            <p>{props.nodeDescription}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

TreeNode.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string
};

// Same approach for defaultProps too
TreeNode.defaultProps = {
  title: "No Title",
};

export default TreeNode;
```